# PHP manage data like a session while in socket context

Tags: php, sockets, session, data-structures, session-variables

I've created a chat with PHP websockets. I want to store data about the user in a session, and change and read that data realtime based on the activities via the websockets.
As I found on the internet, you can't use sessions when the script (the process) is actually a websocket. And it also seems logical to me, because session data can be changed from other processes which will wait for each other.
Since a socket script won't stop because the process is never 'done', you cant read from or write to a session from a socket.

How can I read and write data like it's a session, while I can't use session in combination with a socket (in the same script)?
(Of course in a simple PHP page, without sockets, I can use sessions).

Comment: What I used to do in this case is save a unique id with the username in your database. Set that id in a session on login and make a post request to your socket with that id. The socket can retrieve the actual username based on the id. It's not 100% secure since technically users could try to modify the request headers and guess someones unique id. But it's a lot safer than just sending plain usernames.

Answer (score 0):

An in-memory data cache should suit your needs. It offers to your different processes a common place to read and write data that is faster to access than database or files.

Check out [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) or [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php); both of these are PHP extensions that link up with a Memcached server.  The extensions and the server interact much in the same way that PDO and MySQLi extensions interact with a MySQL server. So you would need to choose one of the extensions and to also install the server ([Memcached homepage](http://www.memcached.org/))

Setting and getting values is really easy. For example:

```
$cache = new Memcache();
$cache->connect('localhost', 11211); // connect to localhost on port 11211
$retrievedVal = $cache->get('some_key'); //get a value from the cache.

$cache->set($keyname, $value, 0, 15*60); //store value in cache for 15 minutes
```

All scripts that connect to the same host will have access to the same cached values.